# create-react-app causing Node.js requests to not go through proxy

Tags: node.js, reactjs, request, electron, create-react-app

I'm currently writing an app with Electron, Create-React-App, and Node.js (note: in electron, webSecurity is disabled to make CORS requests).
In my App.js file I'm trying to write a module to test proxies by sending a request to a site and checking the response, like so

```
var proxiedRequest=request.defaults({'proxy':"http://username:password@test.test.com:0000"})
await proxiedRequest.get(site, function(error, resp, body){
        console.log(resp.statusCode)
        console.log(resp)
}
```

Now I created a separate test.js file that I used to make sure that it was react causing the issues

```
const request = require('request-promise')
var proxyUrl = //working proxy here;
var proxiedRequest = request.defaults({'proxy': proxyUrl});
proxiedRequest.get('http://google.com',function(err, resp, body){
    console.log(err)
    console.log(resp.statusCode)
})
```

And I tested it with both a working and non-working proxy and got the correct responses.

My question is why is create-react-app causing the request to not be routed through the proxy? Is it due to the fact that its being hosted on https://localhost:3000 or is it actually an electron based issue?

Answer (score 0):

you have to add your localhost to your Whitelabel cors in your backend  if your API is made by express you can use cors lib to solve the problem [cors lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors)